# How should I add a changing of nav dots while clicking the next or prev button, and at the same time changing the slide?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying (by using jquery and css)  at the same time to change the slide and navigation dot by clicking at next or prev arrow. 
I am able to change the slide while clicking at the arrows, but I have no idea how to move nav dots in a proper way (slide moves a position and dot moves a position).

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/kamil-dolistowski/pen/jdLjNZ)

```
 // ===== Animate Slide Menu ==== //
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Set options//
    var speed = 500;               //fade speed//
    var autoswitch = true;         //auto slider option//
    var autoswitch_speed = 4000;   //auto slider speed//


    //Adding initial active class//
    $('.j-slide').first().addClass('active');
    //  hide all img slides
    $('.j-slide').hide(); 
    $('.active').show();



    //BTN activation NEXT//
    $('.teamSection__btnRight').on('click', function(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if($('.oldActive') .is(':last-child')){
            $('.j-slide').first().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.j-slide').fadeOut(speed);
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);

    });

    //BTN activation PREV//
    $('.teamSection__btn').on('click', function(){

        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if($('.oldActive') .is(':first-child')){
            $('.teamSection__slide').last().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
        }
        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.teamSection__slide').fadeOut(speed);
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
    });

    //------------------//


    $('.j-circle').first().addClass('j-indicator');
    $('.j-indicator').hide(); 
    $('.j-indicator').show();

    //BTN activation NEXT//





});
```

Comment: Add a `j-indicator` to all of the `circleIndicator` divs, but hidden, then use .show()/.hide() (or add/remove class) - or just move the `div` using append.    The problem is that the `j-indicator` is a div inside `j-circle` but your code makes it appear as if `j-indicator` is a class to be added to `j-circle`  (3rd line from bottom in the code in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the 'next' button's onClick handler:

```
var indicator = $('.j-indicator');
if (indicator.parent().is(':last-child')) {
  indicator.parent().siblings().first().append(indicator);
} else {
  indicator.parent().next().append(indicator);
}
```

And this for the 'previous' button:

```
var indicator = $('.j-indicator');
if (indicator.parent().is(':first-child')) {
  indicator.parent().siblings().last().append(indicator);
} else {
  indicator.parent().prev().append(indicator);
}
```

updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdGxmj